# Uninstall mean.io after init command

Tags: mongodb, gruntjs, npm, mean.io

I installed mean.io using these 2 commands:

```
mean init myApp
cd myApp && npm install
```

Now I'm looking for how to uninstall myApp, at minimum I'd like to remove the data in the database. At best I'd like to remove all traces of myApp on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply `rm -rf myApp/` to get rid of the application files.

If there is still a lingering DB you can open up the mongo shell by typing `mongo`. Then do a `show dbs` to list all the databases and locate the offending DB in the list. Type `use dbnamegoeshere` and then follow that with a `db.dropDatabase()` to drop it. That should take care of everything.

Comment: The `rm -rf myApp/` command took forever to execute, spitted out pages of errors (path too long, directory not empty) and did nothing. I guess this is just unix way of deleting files so I can do it easily in Windows GUI. As for MongoDB, the command work and I saw a `mean-dev` database, at this point I'm still unsure if I can delete it safely. If `mean init myApp` will recreate it then it's ok. If the `mean-dev` db was created by the `npm install -g meanio@latest` command then this is a problem. By the name of the DB

Comment: I figure out the web site is nested inside the main db so still unsure if it's safe to delete it, by the way this is one of the convoluted path mean.io creates after init that is too long to delete with rm -rf: C:\Users\MyName\myApp\node_modules\forever\node_modules\forever-monitor\node_modules\broadway\node_modules\winston\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\test\integration